# yql getting max-response-exceeded 1536000 for 3.2MB data

Tags: http, xpath, yql

I am getting a set of data from a site. the site is poorly made it has all the data with size 3.5 MB in a big table around 8000 rows of data

i am using the following YQL statement

```
select * from html where url="example.com" and xpath="//div[@id='page-1']"
```

Now what i get in the YQL console is this

```
  {
 "query": {
  "count": 0,
  "created": "2015-05-20T04:13:50Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "url": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "1",
     "execution-stop-time": "2076",
     "execution-time": "2075",
     "max-response-exceeded": "1536000",
     "content": "example.com"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "1",
     "execution-stop-time": "2076",
     "execution-time": "2075",
     "max-response-exceeded": "1536000",
     "content": "example.com"
    }
   ],
   "user-time": "2076",
   "service-time": "4150",
   "build-version": "0.2.134"
  },
  "results": null
 }
}
```

How do i go about getting the data?
Is there i way i can make multiple calls and stitch the data?